# Why does ArrayList use transient storage?

Tags: java, arraylist, transient

I was reading the source of Java's ArrayList and I came across its backing array declaration:

```
private transient Object[] elementData;
```

Why does this need to be transient? Why can't this class be serialized?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It *can* be serialized; the `ArrayList` class just takes care of things itself, rather than using the default mechanism. Look at the `writeObject()` and `readObject()` methods in that class, which are part of the standard serialization mechanism.

If you look at the source, you see that `writeObject()` does not save the backing array.  Instead, it serializes the elements (including null values) one at a time up to the `size()` limit.  This avoids the overheads of serializing the array, and especially any unused slots at the end of the array.  On deserialization, a new backing array of the minimum required size is created by `readObject()`.

Answer (score 9):

> Why does this need to be transient?

It does this because it provides custom `readObject` and `writeObject` methods that do a better job of serialization than the default.  Specifically, the writeObject method writes just the size and the sequence of elements.  This avoids serializing the private array object which 1) has its own header and overheads, and 2) is typically padded with `null`s.  The space saving can be significant.

> Why can't this class be serialized?

The `ArrayList` class as a whole can be serialized<sup>1</sup>.  The `Object[]` could be serialized directly, but they chose to mark it as `transient` implement the serialization another way.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, this depends on the elements' runtime types.  For example, if you attempted to serialize an `ArrayList` containing `Thread` references, then you would get a runtime exception for the first non-null reference.</sup>

Comment: Just want to confirm - "the field doesn't strictly need to be declared as transient at all", because the custom `readObject` and `writeObject` are provided in this case?

Comment: That aside was incorrect, and I have removed it.  In fact, readObject / writeObject use the defaultReadObject / writeObject methods to handle some of the fields.  Therefore, the others need to be marked as `transient`.

Answer (score 6):

`ArrayList` implements `Serializable`, so it *can* be serialized, that's exactly why the private backing array is `transient`, so it is not serialized along with other data in the class, since all is handled by `ArrayList`'s `writeObject` and `readObject` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Because it implements explicit serialization. See ArrayList#writeObject.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Stephen C's answer above, I would like to correct his note about transient being used, in `ArrayLists`'s case, for readability. This may be better as a comment under his answer but I don't have that ability yet!

While the field being marked as `transient` is helpful for readability, it is also necessary due to the custom `readObject` and `writeObject` methods calling `java.io.ObjectInputStream`'s `defaultReadObject` and `java.io.ObjectOutputStream`'s `defaultWriteObject` methods respectively. These methods will do the dirty work of handling serializiation of all the fields not marked `transient` (e.g. `size`).

See the source code for `ObjectOutputStream` for more details here: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java#L431

Comment: Yea ... I just noticed that myself.  Corrected my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The variable isn't serializable.

- If the variable isn't serializable, then the serialization mechanism will throw an exception when it tries to serialize the variable. To avoid this, you can declare the variable to be transient.

The variable is redundant.

- Suppose that the instance caches the result of a computation. Locally, we might want
  to store the result of the computation, in order to save some processor time. But 
  when we send the object over the wire, we might worry more about consuming bandwidth
  and thus discard the cached computation since we can always regenerate it later on.

link: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/JavaRMI_10/index.html?page=3

Comment: These do not explain why `elementData` is marked as `transient` in this case. 1) The `Object[]` elements will be serializable or else serialization of the `ArrayList` will fail. 2) The elements of an `ArrayList` are not "redundant".  See other answers for the correct explanation.